# Algorithm to effectively split money in group

Tags: java, algorithm

Hi I am working on application which will manage expenses in group of users. I would like to know, how to most effectively get final settlement instructions for users. I have came up with this:

```java
@Override
    public Map<Pair<User, User>, BigDecimal> getSettlementInstructions(Group group) {
        Map<Pair<User, User>, BigDecimal> settlementInstructions = new HashMap<>();
        var currentBalance = getCurrentBalanceAlternative(group);
        var positiveBalances = currentBalance.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)>=0)
                .sorted(Map.Entry.<User,BigDecimal>comparingByValue().reversed())
                .toList();
        var negativeBalances = currentBalance.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)<0)
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                .toList();

        var negativePointer = negativeBalances.get(0);

        while (!negativePointer.getValue().equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)){
            var positivePointer = positiveBalances.get(0);
            var pointerDifference = positivePointer.getValue().add(negativePointer.getValue());
            if(pointerDifference.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)<0){
                settlementInstructions.put(Pair.of(negativePointer.getKey(), positivePointer.getKey()), positivePointer.getValue());
                negativePointer.setValue(pointerDifference);
                positivePointer.setValue(BigDecimal.ZERO);
                positiveBalances = positiveBalances.stream()
                        .sorted(Map.Entry.<User,BigDecimal>comparingByValue().reversed())
                        .toList();
                negativeBalances = negativeBalances.stream()
                        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                        .toList();
            }else {
                settlementInstructions.put(Pair.of(negativePointer.getKey(), positivePointer.getKey()), negativePointer.getValue().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(-1)));
                negativePointer.setValue(BigDecimal.ZERO);
                positivePointer.setValue(pointerDifference);
                positiveBalances = positiveBalances.stream()
                        .sorted(Map.Entry.<User,BigDecimal>comparingByValue().reversed())
                        .toList();
                negativeBalances = negativeBalances.stream()
                        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                        .toList();
            }
            negativePointer = negativeBalances.get(0);
        }

        return settlementInstructions;
    }
```

to me it seems quite complicated for such a simple task, but I can not find better solution. Thank you all for help.

PS `getCurrentBalanceAlternative(group)` method returns `Map<User,BigDecimal>` representing the balance of individual user (how much money he will get - positive balance / owe - negative balance)

Comment: Please add a problem statement.

Comment: Please also show the definitions for `User` and `Group`

Comment: I will add all of those.

Comment: "Most effectively" is a bit vague. What are you looking to optimize for? If I understand the problem statement correctly, this is a variant of the Knapsack problem, and getting the most efficient solution is going to be computationally expensive.

Comment: https://pure.tue.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/2062204/623903.pdf

Comment: And if you just need a good-enough solution, consider asking for optimal readability instead of performance. Chances are very strong that the time difference between a readable and a fast solution will be negligible.